# How to create iterable loop in css selector

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I got 25 links like this

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.v-table-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(i) > td:nth-child(4) > div > div > a').click()
```

and try to click them all by:

```
for i in range (1,25):
    link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.v-table-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(i) > td:nth-child(4) > div > div > a')
    link.click()
    print(link)
    time.sleep(1)
```

So i think that something wrong in my code, cause i get an error =)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/python_1pk/get_response.py", line 29, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.v-table-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(i) > td:nth-child(4) > div > div > a').click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 598, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.82)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osU9r.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there's an issue with your CSS selector.
You are trying to form it as `'.v-table-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(i) > td:nth-child(4) > div > div > a'`, but in this notation, the `i` variable does not get substituted to it's value.

Try using an f-string:

```py
selector = f".v-table-table > tbody > tr:nth-child({i}) > td:nth-child(4) > div > div > a"
```

Note the curly braces around `i` - it's literally "place the value of the `i` variable here"

Comment: Oh, great! Really forgot about f-string. That works brilliantly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know how your page look like I assume it will be like this stackoverflow pages :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?tab=newest&page=2&pagesize=15 .
I tried to click on every link to do so I used the full xpath (you can use normal I think). With the xpath you find where is the article number so you can create a for loop and cThere is a code I tried I hope it will help you :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(Your path to the chromedriver)
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?tab=newest&page=2&pagesize=15"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h3/a"  #xpath of the first title page 
"/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[15]/div/div[2]/h3/a" #xpath of the last title page 
for k in range(1,16):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div["+str(k)+"]/div/div[2]/h3/a").click()
    "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div"
    print("clicked")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get(url)lick on every article.
```

Comment: Thank you, but i tried this method. it doesn't work for me.